# SSIS Deployment Variable Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have created an SSIS package which uses a for each loop container and an Excel connection string that I have created from a variable so I can loop through multiple files. My package works without issue and if I have a number of files in my source folder and I simply execute the package it works perfectly looping through all the files doing what I want it to do.

The issue I have is when I deploy the package, If I have files within my source folder it executes without error but when you look at the source folder it still has the files in. When digging a bit deeper in to the package reports it looks like it is reporting that there were no files found. If I manually execute the dtsx file in runs without issue and imports everything as it should.

Is there any reason why after deploying the package it is unable to recognise the files or the variable that I store the file name in?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be permissions related. Does the SQL Server Service account have permissions to the directory where the files are stored?

Comment: Hi - Yes it looks to have the permissions

Comment: This must be a comment, not an answer?!

Comment: Yes, it probably is, but, since I don't have the ability to add comments yet and still wanted to help out, I thought I'd do it this way.